# SVN Error: Can't convert string from native encoding to 'UTF-8'

Tags: linux, svn, version-control

I've got a post-commit hook script that performs a SVN update of a working copy when commits are made to the repository.

When users commit to the repository from their Windows machines using TortoiseSVN they get the following error:

```
post-commit hook failed (exit code 1) with output:
svn: Error converting entry in directory '/home/websites/devel/website/guides/Images' to UTF-8
svn: Can't convert string from native encoding to 'UTF-8':
svn: Teneriffa-S?\195?\188d.jpg
```

The file in question above is: `Teneriffa-Süd.jpg` notice the accented u. This is because the site is German and the files have been spelt in German.

When executing a update on the working copy at the Linux command-line no errors are encountered. The above error only exists when the post-commit hook is executed via a commit by a Windows SVN client.

Questions:

1. Why would SVN try to change the encoding of a file?
2. Are filenames allowed to contain chars that are outside the Windows standard ASCII ones?

---

Update:

It turns out that the file in question's filename correctly displays as `Teneriffa-Süd.jpg` when viewed from a Windows machine (via Samba) but when I view the filename from the Linux server (using SSH and PuTTY) where the file resides I get `Teneriffa-SÃ¼d.jpg`

Comment: A quick note:  The discrepancy in filename between Samba + Windows and SSH +PuTTY is probably the result of PuTTY's configuration rather than anything to do with your problem.  Under PuTTY's Window, Translation, the "Remote Character Set" option probably needs to be changed to UTF-8.

Comment: For me, the problem was with non-ASCII characters in my commit message.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. It does not change the encoding of the file. It changes the encoding of the filename (to something that every client can hopefully understand).
2. Allowed by whom ? NTFS uses 16-bit code points, and Windows can expose the file names in various encodings, based on how you ask for it (it will try to convert them to the encoding you ask for). Now... That bit (how you ask) depends on the specific svn client you use. It sounds to me like a bug in TortoiseSVN.

Edit to add:

Ugh. I misunderstood the symptoms. the svn server stores everything in utf-8 (and it seems that it did that successfully).

The post-commit hook is the bit that fails to convert from UTF-8. If I understand what you're saying correctly, the post-commit hook on the server triggers an svn update to a shared drive (the svn server therefore starts an svn client to itself...) ? This means that the configuration that needs to be fixed is the one for the client *on the server*. 
<strike>Check the LANG / LC_ALL on the environment executing the svn server.</strike>. As it happens, the hooks are run in a [vacuum environment](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch05s02.html#svn-ch-5-sect-2.1) (see Tip). So you should set the variable in the hook itself.

See also [this page](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.2/svn.advanced.l10n.html) for info on how svn handles localisation

Comment: The file name `Teneriffa-Süd.jpg` is correctly displayed in my working copy on my Windows machine as well as the the working copy that the post-commit hook is trying to update which resides on a Linux server (same server as repositories) when the folder is viewed in Windows using a samba share.

But when when I do a `ls` in the folder at the Linux command-line I get: `Teneriffa-SÃ¼d.jpg`

Comment: that probably just means that the filename holds data that is directly UTF-8 encoded (not surprising since the conversion failed), and windows parses that fine, while your linux box is not configured to see UTF-8 filenames, so it reads it as whatever codepage it wants.

Comment: Yes you are correct in that the SVN client that fails in the client on the server itself. I'll have a look at the links you sent me and get back to you.

Comment: +1 for saying that the hooks are run in a vacuum environment, then export LANG=xxxxx do the trick

Answer (score 72):

Yet another example:

```
$ svn update
svn: Error converting entry in directory '.' to UTF-8
svn: Can't convert string from native encoding to 'UTF-8':

$ export LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8

$ svn update
```

(... and all is fine now)

Comment: I added the export statement to the top of my pre-commit file and it works.

````export LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8````

Comment: Example for Brazilian Portuguese (cedilla, a acute, etc):

`export LC_CTYPE=pt_BR.UTF-8`

Comment: Spanish from Spain, worked using: export LC_CTYPE=es_ES.UTF-8

Comment: I also had to unset `LC_ALL`, or set it to `en_US.UTF-8`.

Answer (score 8):

If Error is -

```
[abc@288832-web3 public_html]$ svn update
svn: Error converting entry in directory 'images' to UTF-8
svn: Valid UTF-8 data
(hex: 46 65 6e 65 72 62 61 68)
followed by invalid UTF-8 sequence
(hex: e7 65 2b 46)
```

Then do this.

```
[abc@288832-web3 public_html]$ printf "\x46\x65\x6e\x65\x72\x62\x61\x68\n"
Fenerbah
```

(This means that the system has some file name starting with "Fenerbah" in that folder.)

```
[abc@288832-web3 public_html]$ cd  images
[abc@288832-web3 images]$ rm -rf Fenerbahçe+Forma+2.jpg
```

So you can see that there is a special character in the name and it is not supported by SVN.

Comment: some more tips and tricks in this post http://arjuna.deltoso.net/index.html%3Fp=334.html

Answer (score 4):

Don't forget to generate those locales in your system
(as root) 

example for Ru

```
locale-gen ru_RU.CP1251
locale-gen ru_RU.UTF-8
dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Comment: You should as least mention what system these commands are meant for, they are not standard commands.

Comment: dpkg-reconfigure locales did the trick for me. I added my locale and all works fine now.

Answer (score 4):

put this in your post-commit
export LANG=xxxxx (your lang)

Comment: One line and problem solved. I was trying LANG without the export for half an hour. :-( You do need to install your locale [doing this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=196414).

Answer (score 4):

Just use the following line in your script before executing any svn command.
User appropriate language codes, in following example I used japanese

```
export LC_ALL=ja_JP.UTF8
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems that all LC_ varables need .UTF8 at the end.  For example, I happened to have LC_ALL, LC_TIME, and LC_CTYPE defined.  After setting LC_CTYPE the problem was not solved, so I needed to type LC_ALL as well and then it worked:

```
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_DK.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
```

In order to avoid the problem again, I copied the file to a different name, removed the old one from svn, added new one to svn, and send a message to a collaborator not to do this.

Comment: You are right. My LC_TYPE was set to POSIX. The svn cliente could not convert latins chars to UTF-8. Changing the encoding to the locale LC_TYPE="en_US.UTF-8" solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

1. It changes the encoding to a location-neutral encoding in case someone with a *different* encoding checks it out.
2. Of course. But it's not "Windows" ASCII (Windows actually uses some strange encoding like CP1251 or so).

The best way to fix this is to make sure that your system uses UTF-8 whenever possible (check `$LANG`).

Comment: echoed that system variable in Linux and it returned `en_GB.UTF-8` which implies that it is using UTF-8

Comment: I meant that it should be echoed on your local system, but it doesn't apply if you're running Windows, so never mind.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar problem when running "svn add" on a directory, but the solution was different.  I couldn't see the "hex" digits using printf (actually no hex output was shown by svn), but this command allowed me to see the results, and fix it:

```
LC_ALL=C svn add probealign
```

I think, in general, sticking LC_ALL=C before your command allows you to see the offending files... and is a lot easier than pasting in a lot of \x72 stuff (which apparently may not be available).

Answer (score 0):

For information, I got this error on commit `native encoding to 'UTF-8'`with a windows client tortoise svn,

when my URL of repository was :

> http://x.x.x.x/svn/myrepos

I changed my URL of repository for :

> svn://x.x.x.x/myrepos

and now all is perferct.

I think this information will be useful to some.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had the setting in ~/.subversion/config as below

`log-encoding = ...`

Commenting it worked.