# Howto Config mod_dav_svn locale under apache2?

Tags: svn, apache2, locale, mod-dav-svn

I have install and config ALL the apache2 & mod_dav_svn, but when access the http://host/svn/ , got this:

ps:the /mnt/svn/ is the parsent of all svn repos. and the repos is named using utf8 already.

os: ubuntu 11.10 server 64bit
apache2 -v
Server version: Apache/2.2.20 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Feb 14 2012 16:35:38

locale: also export in /etc/apache2/envvars
    LANG=zh_CN.UTF-8
    LANGUAGE=zh_CN
    LC_CTYPE="zh_CN.UTF-8"
    LC_NUMERIC="zh_CN.UTF-8"
    LC_TIME="zh_CN.UTF-8"
    LC_COLLATE="zh_CN.UTF-8"
    LC_MONETARY="zh_CN.UTF-8"
    LC_MESSAGES="zh_CN.UTF-8"
    LC_PAPER="zh_CN.UTF-8"
    LC_NAME="zh_CN.UTF-8"
    LC_ADDRESS="zh_CN.UTF-8"
    LC_TELEPHONE="zh_CN.UTF-8"
    LC_MEASUREMENT="zh_CN.UTF-8"
    LC_IDENTIFICATION="zh_CN.UTF-8"
    LC_ALL=zh_CN.UTF-8

> [Wed Feb 29 14:54:34 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.20 (Ubuntu) DAV/2 SVN/1.6.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
>
> [Wed Feb 29 14:54:42 2012] [error] [client ] Unable to deliver content.  [500, #0]
>   [Wed Feb 29 14:54:42 2012] [error] [client *] couldn't fetch dirents of SVNParentPath  [500, #22]
>
> [Wed Feb 29 14:54:42 2012] [error] [client *] Error converting entry in directory '/mnt/svn' to UTF-8  [500, #22]
>
> [Wed Feb 29 14:54:42 2012] [error] [client *] Can't convert string from native encoding to 'UTF-8':  [500, #22]
>
> [Wed Feb 29 14:54:42 2012] [error] [client *] ?\231?\160?\148?\229?\143?\145?\233?\131?\168?\231?\174?\161?\231?\144?\134  [500, #22]

Comment: Just to be sure: would this question help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116718/svn-error-cant-convert-string-from-native-encoding-to-utf-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit /etc/apache2/envvars, change LANG from C to your locale language setting.

I did the following modification, then restarted apache2, no more problem.

export LANG=C --> export LANG="en_US.UTF-8"

Answer (score 0):

You haven't *somewhere* support of your zh_CN.UTF-8. It can be:

- Ubuntu

check readability of `ls  /mnt/svn/`

- Apache

create http-only location, add to it some zh_CN.UTF-8 named files and directories, disable DirectoryIndex and verify result in browser for readability

<strike>I suppose, test #2 will failed</strike>

**Edit**

From the subversion book:

> Errors like this typically occur when the **Subversion client** has
>   received a UTF-8 string from the repository, but not all of the
>   characters in that string can be represented using the encoding of the
>   current locale. For example, if your locale is en_US but a
>   collaborator has committed a Japanese filename, you're likely to see
>   this error when you receive the file during an svn update.

To fix this error message you have to set your current locale appropriately

Comment: ls /mnt/svn/ works fine & the chars all right. even ls /mnt/svn/ > file && iconv -f utf8 -t utf8 file will pass.

Comment: ln -s /mnt/svn/ to htdocs and browse thought apache2 ... all right , and every things rihgt except svn mod...