# How can I redirect text and get utf-8 in windows?

Tags: windows, powershell, svn, utf-8, utf-16

if I redirect the output of a program (svn in my case) in powershell to a file, the output is in UTF-16. Can I get it as UTF-8 instead? how?

Comment: How do you redirect output at the moment? By `>` operator, piping to `Out-File`, some other way?

Comment: @vonPryz Just >

Comment: @StefanoBorini use [Out-File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file?view=powershell-6) with the encoding you want. The default is UTF16. Windows strings are UTF16 so the default makes sense

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos is there a way to make > default to utf-8?

Comment: @StefanoBorini check the  [about_Redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-6) help page. It explains the redirection options and operators

Comment: @StefanoBorini why? That would break every script in production. Windows strings *are* UTF16, which means UTF16 text can be read without conversions or risking encoding errors. Do you have a specific issue with encodings perhaps? Are you trying to feed the output to a non-Unicode program or copy it to a Linux machine?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos because if I redirect with svn diff a patch, and then have to upload the patch to something that does not understand the dumb windows encoding, I don't want to tell everybody to just pipe it through out-file and specify the encoding to utf-8 every time, because it's guaranteed they will screw it up more often than not

Comment: @StefanoBorini use Out-File. Or configure svn to use UTF8. I'm pretty sure svn configures this during installation but I've moved to git 5 years ago. In a mixed Windows/Linux environment with the `git` server hosted on Linux too

Comment: @StefanoBorini check [SVN Error: Can't convert string from native encoding to 'UTF-8'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116718/svn-error-cant-convert-string-from-native-encoding-to-utf-8) too.

Comment: Do you need this for `svnadmin dump` and `svnadmin load`?

Answer (score -1):

After you get the output in UTF-16, you can then convert it to UTF-8 maybe? The way to do it can be done is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/750453/4729168).

The meaningful part in your case is

```
Set-Content -Encoding UTF8
```